# Python - Count the occurrence of a same value in two differents columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

From a dataframe like this :

```
id1  id2  label
1    3      0
2    1      1
3    2      1
```

where label values are only 0 and 1, I would like to have the following result :

```
id  count
1     2
2     1
3     0
```

Where count is the sum of the number of times the id in id1 has been matched to a label 0 and the number of times the same id in id2 has been matched to a label 1. And where id is the column of all the unique ids beetween id1 and id2.

I tried this : `df.groupby(['id1', 'label']).size()` but from there I am stuck.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The logic is confusing. How is id `3` having count `0`?

Comment: Because when 3 is in id2 the label value is 0 so it does not count and when 3 is in id1 the label value is 1 so it does not count either

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty ugly but works:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

# create our df
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,2,3],'id2':[3,1,2], 'label':[0,1,1]})

# collect all ids involved
all_ids = df['id1'].append(df['id2']).unique()

# count ids in id1, id2 columns per the rules
d1 = dict(Counter(df[df['label']==0]['id1']))
d2 = dict(Counter(df[df['label']==1]['id2']))

# add up the counts and put into a df
counts = {id : d1.get(id,0) + d2.get(id,0) for id in all_ids}
df_out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient = 'index', columns = ['count']).rename_axis('id')

df_out
```

produces

```
    count
id  
1   2
2   1
3   0
```